# RSS feed response does not come in original XML format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss, cross-domain

I am using jquery.xdomainajax.js to make a cross domain call. But, the result of fetching the RSS feed that comes back is not in the original XML format. It makes it impossible to parse. The original RSS feed is correct and valid.

Here's what I'm using right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"> </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $.get('http://example.com/feed/', function(res) {
              var string = res.responseText;
              alert(string);
          });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Cross domain mod for jQuery](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) you are using is using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) underneath.

By default, this mod will return an HTML file because it's fetching from the "html" YQL data table, which ends up wrapping it in HTML. You want it to instead grab from the "rss" or "feed" data table type.

To your copy of jquery.xdomainajax.js you'll need to edit on line 19:

```
query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';
```

to the following

```
query = 'select * from rss where url="{URL}"';
```

And on line 59, from

```
responseText: (data.results[0] || '')
  // YQL screws with <script>s
  // Get rid of them
  .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
```

to

```
responseText: data.results
```

If you don't do the second change you'll only get the first item in the RSS feed.